# Cannot find models, views and controllers folders in my app folder in Laravel structure

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I just created a new Laravel framework project with:

```
laravel new <nameofproject>
```

After the creation, from what I have seen in tutorials online there is meant to be `models`, `views` and `controllers` folders in the `app` directory of the project but they are not there, how do I still move forward with this problem?

Comment: You're using laravel 5, but you're reading a tutorial for laravel 4. The views are in `your_laravel_dir/resources/views`, controllers are in `app\Http\Controllers` and models you create on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**laravel new** command creates a copy of what you can find on https://github.com/laravel/laravel. As you can see, there is **no models folder** in **Laravel 5** setup. It was there in **Laravel 4**, so it seems you are using **tutorials that are out of date**.

Comment: Thanks jedrzej. There's now a folder more(vendor folder) than the one in the git link in what I installed. Thanks anyway. SO now I have to add the folders myself.

Comment: Vendor is a folder where all the dependencies are installed when you run "laravel new". They are not stored in the git repository of laravel but in their own repositories, that's why there is no vendor folder.

Comment: @DIPXOID From Laravel 5 onwards the _models_ folder is completely removed I so that you can follow _Design Patterns_ i believe (but not sure). The _views_ folder is located at `.resources/views` and the _controllers_ are located at `./app/Http/Controllers`.